# Ambiguous CORS error when uploading object to S3 with presigned url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I'm generating an S3 presigned URL on my Express server like this:

```
const presignedUrl = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
    Bucket: `bucket`,
    Key: `key`,
    ContentType: "image/*"
});
```

I then send this URL to the client (React) so that the user can upload an image using the presigned url. I do so like this:

```
const myHeaders = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'image/*' });
const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: file 
});
```

However, after I try uploading the object, I get this error back from S3:

```
{
    body: (...)
    bodyUsed: false
    headers: Headers {}
    ok: false
    redirected: false
    status: 403
    statusText: "Forbidden"
    type: "cors" 
    url: "https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/key?Content-Type=image%2F%2A&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential={credential}&X-Amz-Date=20211126T000212Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Signature={signature}&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host"
}
```

I know people get CORS errors but I haven't seen an ambiguous one like this. Moreover, the preflight check returns 200. Here is my bucket's CORS policy

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

This is all in local development so my server is on http://localhost:5000 and my client is on http://localhost:3000. Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Comment: That's not a CORS error. `type: "cors"` is just the [_mode_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode) `fetch` used (it's the default for cross-origin requests). See also [Response.type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/type)

Comment: Thanks Phil, if it weren't for your answer, I would have been chasing up a CORS error for days. I managed to fix it, you can see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this! Turns out when I was setting my credentials as environment variables, I used `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` instead of `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`.